# How to get value of flatpicker using javascript in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, typescript

I am not able to get value of flat picker start date and end date inside my typescript code. I tried with different javascript code but did not found proper solution.

Comment: There is a need of more information related to the issue you raise. Start with version info of the software you use and which platform. Try to get some error information and post that as well. Explain also briefly what you tried so far to fix it yourself. Your question as it is right now triggers "triage review" and that is not what you want I assume. End of review: moved to Editing.

Comment: Briefly describe your problem. Then any kind problem easy to understand for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried by using class name to get value of date.

document.getElementsByClassName("ng2-flatpickr-input")[0].value

but found proper solution after so many trail.

(document.getElementsByClassName("ng2-flatpickr-input")[0]).value